# UIView continuous animation that repeats using a different frame iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing an animation on a UIView and having it repeat, which is working well like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:6.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.imgTopCloud.frame = CGRectMake(-self.imgTopCloud.frame.size.width, self.imgTopCloud.frame.origin.y, self.imgTopCloud.frame.size.width, self.imgTopCloud.frame.size.height);
}completion:nil];
```

This animates it outside of the view's bounds. Now, when it does that, I want the `imgTopCloud`'s frame to start right at the very end of the view like this:

```
//Now we start at the very right
self.imgTopCloud.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.imgTopCloud.frame.origin.y, self.imgTopCloud.frame.size.width, self.imgTopCloud.frame.size.height);
```

The issue is, when the animation starts to repeat, it brings it back to `imgTopCloud`'s original starting frame, not the new one I want. I tried putting the new frame in the completion block of the `animateWithDuration` message, but no dice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't repeat that animation.  Instead, in the completion block of that animation, you need to do two things.
1) set the frame to the very right
2) start a repeating animation that moves the view to the left